# How to update huge XLSM or XLSX file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, sax

I have a problem about updating a huge `XLSX` file.

Despite I was able to read a `XLSX` with this solution : [Reading huge XLSX](http://lchenaction.blogspot.fr/2013/12/how-to-read-super-large-excel-and-csv.html) (Sax and XSSF)
and to write with this solution : [Writing huge XLSX](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf) (SXSSF based on Sax and XSSF )

I don't know how to update a `XLSM` file with `macros` and `datas`.

Is there any idea?

Comment: Use normal XSSF having bought some more memory for your server?

Comment: I can't modify servers's configuration and the memory is very limited.